# Webpack 2 eslint-loader auto fix

Tags: webpack, eslint, webpack-2

In webpack 1.x I could use the eslint property in my webpack config to enable autofixing my linting errors using:

```
...

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './src/app.js',
  eslint: {
    configFile: '.eslintrc',
    fix: true
  },

...
```

However, in webpack 2.x, thusfar I have been unable to use the auto fix functionality, because I don't know where to set it in my webpack config. Using the eslint property in my webpack configFile throws an `WebpackOptionsValidationError`.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The most common way to *auto fix linting rules with webpack v2* (and higher) is to use the [`eslint-loader`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-loader).

In your `webpack.config.js` you would do:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/, // both .js and .jsx
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        include: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'src'),
        enforce: 'pre',
        options: {
          fix: true,
        },
      },
      // ...
    ],
  },
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank Glenn. I had exactly the same rule set in my config. Except I was using `use: 'eslint-loader'` in stead of `loader: 'eslint-loader'`. I was under the impression that those keys had identical functionality (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-loader), but the difference is that `use` needs an Array as value and `loader` requires just a String.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack 5 with eslint-webpack-plugin:

```
  const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');
  ....
  plugins: [
    ...
    new ESLintPlugin({fix: true}),
    ...
  ]
```